# Resizing background on window resize with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I'm trying to resize the background image of my website to fit whatever width and height the current window is using jQuery.

currently i am doing this

```
$(window).resize(function()
        {

            $("body").css({"background-size" : "100% 100%"});

        });
```

That causes the background to not display at all. if i omit one of the 100%, it stretches to the width but not the height. I am not sure what im missing here.

Comment: 100% 100% should resize itself, should it not?

Comment: If you want to fill the background using an image (and keeping the ratio) you can easily use CSS3 `background-size: cover;`

Comment: background-size: cover is IE 9+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use css only.

```
html{
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I used html instead of body since it's always 100% 100% which is great for backgrounds.

Comment: The problem is that if the aspect ratio makes the window taller than it is wide, the background image doesnt stretch to fit and so there is ugly whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
    $("body").css({"background-size" : "100% 100%"});
```

is optimized into

```
    $("body").css({"background-size" : "100%"});
```

maybe you can trick your css into this:

```
    $("body").attr( "style" , "background-size: 100% 100%" );
```

Comment: it doesnt seem to like that. i Dont think it's optimizing it to 100%, because then i'd actually see my background image, instead of it disappearing altogether

Comment: I mean jQuery seems to be optimizing it. If I inspect the 100% 100% attribute it is changed to ( a single ) 100% in the inspector. Something that doesn't seem to happen when sending "100% 99%".

Comment: Nope, it still isnt displaying anything at all...Perhaps some of my other code is interfering with it. You can see the original problem on my website at tomsterk.com, but it isnt resizing the background based on background-size (near the bottom of my javascript)

Comment: Actually, the background image size is the window width but 0 pixels tall, according to chrome. Im not sure what causes that